# It is possible to persist Redux store to SQLite in react native?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, redux, redux-persist

I am developing an application in react native, in which I want to store the API's data in SQLite as local DB and also want to use Redux as global state management.

So, It is possible to persist the Redux store to SQLite? If possible what will be the procedure?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Your "getter" function needs to implement the logic to "get data from local database" or "fetch data from api". Your actions will get more complex. Maybe create helper functions that implement the logic of fetching fresh data or getting local data, depending on the online state or timestamps of the data/checksums.

Answer (score -2):

you can use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) or [react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)

SQLite db should be implemented on backend, and in react-native code, you should not embed a DB directly

Comment: I request you to have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: Using a local SQLite DB in apps is the way to go if you have more complex data then a Key-Value store is made for or you want to develop an offlien app.